# Rails posts show up blank, not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, posts

I tried to submit a new post and I get the error

> "Title can't be blank"

So I removed the validations in my model and after trying again and posting something, the post is just blank, no data is saved whatsoever.

I don't know what to do, I stuck on this one, help!

Update!

Here is the form

```
<% @post.tags.build %>
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true } do |post_form| %>
 <% if @post.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:      </h2>

  <ul>
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>


<div class="field">
<%= post_form.file_field :photo %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
   <%= post_form.label :title %><br />
   <%= post_form.text_field :title %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
<%= post_form.label :url %><br />
<%= post_form.text_field :url %>
</div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= post_form.label :company %><br />
   <%= post_form.text_field :company %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= post_form.label :language %><br />
  <%= post_form.text_field :language %>
</div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= post_form.label :framework %><br />
  <%= post_form.text_field :framework %>
 </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= post_form.label :details %><br />
   <%= post_form.text_area :details %>
 </div>
 <h2>Tags</h2>
<%= render :partial => 'tags/form' ,
            :locals => {:form => post_form } %>
<div class="actions">
    <%= post_form.submit %>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

here is the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "franklinexpress", :password => "osxuser8", :except => [:index, :show, :new, :edit]

#def search
 #     @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
 #   end






# GET /posts
# GET /posts.json
 def index
   @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
   # @posts = Post.all
    # respond_to do |format|
     #format.html # index.html.erb
     #format.json { render json: @posts }
   #end
 end

 # GET /posts/1
 # GET /posts/1.json
 def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @post }
   end
 end

 # GET /posts/new
 # GET /posts/new.json
 def new
   @post = Post.new

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # new.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @post }
   end
 end

   # GET /posts/1/edit
   def edit
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
   else
     format.html { render action: "new" }
     format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
 def update
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
       format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
       format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

   # DELETE /posts/1
   # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
       format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

in my model:

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :title, :presence => true
 validates :url, :presence => true
 validates :company, :presence => true
 validates :language, :presence => true
 validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 4.megabytes
 validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

 has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :tags

  attr_accessor :photo_file_name
  attr_accessor :photo_content_type
  attr_accessor :photo_file_size
  attr_accessor :photo_updated_at
  attr_accessible :photo

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => :true,
   :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
   #paperclip-------------------------------
   has_attached_file :photo,
                 :url => "/assests/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                 :path =>   ":rails_root/public/assets/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"


   #:style => {:small => "150x200>"}

   def self.search(search)
    if search
     where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    # find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end    

 end
```

and in new.html.erb:

```
<div id="header-wrap">
<%= image_tag("walLogotiny.png") %>
<div id="searchbartop">
            <%= form_tag posts_path, :method => :get do%>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] ,"size" => 100 %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
            <% end %>
</div>

</div>
<div id="container">
<h2>New Site Submission</h2>
<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your form is not connected to the model, or you assign attributes incorrectly. It would be really nice to see the view (the form) and the controller action code

Comment: Please show the corosponding view containing the `form_for`.

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to check which post data is sent to the server. You can also try to debug the `params` hash by setting a breakpoint in your `PostsController#create` action.

Comment: finally got it! In my model I replaced 'attr_accessible' to 'attar_accessor' and that fixed it, good as new. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line in your model:

```
  attr_accessible :photo
```

You make only the photo attribute mass-assignable. All other attributes, including the title, are dropped when you create a new post.

Try this:

```
attr_accessible :photo, :title
```

It will now accept the title, but not the other attributes.

edit: didn't see your own comment above, but you figured it out already.